# Lambda expressions: why no argument type inference?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++0x and the Lack of Polymorphic Lambdas - Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643039/c0x-and-the-lack-of-polymorphic-lambdas-why)

C++0x lambda expressions support return type inference to some point. Why aren't argument types determined automatically, too?

Eg, why can't I write:

```
void somefunc(const std::vector<int>& v) 
{
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](x, y) { return x < y; });
}
```

It would seem that the compiler should be able to figure out that `x` and `y` are of type `int`.

Comment: Such functionality is called *polymorphism*, the search term for you is *polymorphic lambda's*. It's a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643039/c0x-and-the-lack-of-polymorphic-lambdas-why). (And yes, it'd be *really* nice to have, but we don't. Sucks.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was searching through SO, but didn't know what to look for.