# Template C++0x lambda function... or functor/predicate?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I have recently upgraded my `g++` so I can enjoy lambda functions.
Everything is great and I am very thankful to those who made it possible in C++ and gcc in particular. There is only one thing that I can't seem to solve - how to have lambda's arguments to be templated? Below are basic examples of lambda usage to demonstrate the problem.

Example #1, everything is yummy:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct bar {
    bar () {}

    void say () {
        printf ("bar::say()\n");
    }

    void say () const {
        printf ("bar::say() const\n");
    }
};

template <typename T>
void do_work (const T & pred) {
    bar b;
    pred (b);
}

int main () {
    do_work ([] (bar & b) { b.say (); });
}
```

Now, assume that `do_work` now invokes predicate two times with different argument types. So here goes example #2:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct foo {
    foo () {}

    void say () {
        printf ("foo::say()\n");
    }

    void say () const {
        printf ("foo::say() const\n");
    }
};

struct bar {
    bar () {}

    void say () {
        printf ("bar::say()\n");
    }

    void say () const {
        printf ("bar::say() const\n");
    }
};

template <typename T>
void do_work (const T & pred) {
    const foo f;
    bar b;
    pred (f);
    pred (b);
}

int main () {
    do_work ([] (auto & b) { b.say (); });
}
```

Note `auto` keyword. I also tried templating it in-place. Don't try to compile that with gcc, here is what I get:

```
./test.cpp:31:5: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
```

But you get the idea. I can solve it with new function declaration style, in theory, but that's not the point. Here is what I really am trying to do, but with simplified syntax (`foo`, `bar` and `do_work` are stripped for simplicity sake):

```
struct pred_t {
    pred_t () = default;

    template <typename T>
    void operator () (T && obj) const {
        obj.say ();
    }
};

int main () {
    do_work (pred_t ());
}
```

Is there a way, or at least plans, to add support for not fully specialized lambda functions, so that they will act sort of like a predicate with `template <typename T> operator () (T &&)`? I don't even know how to name it, lambda predicate maybe? Please let me know your thoughts! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These were discussed as "polymorphic lambdas", and were declined because it made problems with the concepts proposal.

<strike>Last year</strike> [2009 at the Frankfurt meeting](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/218600111), the concepts proposal was voted out of the working paper, but polymorphic lambdas weren't considered anymore for C++0x.

See [C++0x and the Lack of Polymorphic Lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643039/c0x-and-the-lack-of-polymorphic-lambdas-why).

Answer (score 1):

```
do_work ([] (auto & b) { b.say (); });
```

I think the `auto` keyword is not allowed in function/lambda parameter.